# Why is the optional return() method of es6 iterator interface take in an value argument. And why does it need to return an IteratorResult object?

Tags: ecmascript-6, interface, iterator

This is the es6 Iterator interface expressed in TypeScript (copy from explore es6 by Axel Rauschmayer

```js
interface Iterable {
    [Symbol.iterator]() : Iterator;
}
interface Iterator {
    next() : IteratorResult;
    return?(value? : any) : IteratorResult;
}
interface IteratorResult {
    value: any;
    done: boolean;
}
```

Question1: Why is the optional return() method of es6 iterator interface take in one argument? (value? : any)

Question2: And why does it need to return an IteratorResult object?

Comment: Code example please?  Not sure exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure we're on the same page, the `.return` method of an iterator generally behaves as a forced `return` at the currently-suspended location when called. That means no further code in the function itself will actually run. For a snippet like:

```
var makeIter = function*(){};
var iter = makeIter();
```

doing

```
var result = iter.return(4);
// { value: 4, done: true }
```

> Can anyone think of a use case where the optional return method of an es6 iterator need to receive a value?

What else would it return? It could be hard-coded to return `undefined`, but it doesn't seem like there's much of a reason not to allow specifying a return value.

> ... return an IteratorResult?

What should it return if not that? While not handled by most callers of iterators, technically another `yield` could run when you call `.return` so it might not have actually finished executing the iterable yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Question2: why does it need to return an IteratorResult object?

```js
function* gen(){
      yield 123;
      return 'ended value';
   }

   let iter = gen();
   
   console.log(iter.next());//{value: 123, done: false}
   console.log(iter.next());//{value: "ended value", done: true}
   
   iter = gen();//restart iter;
   console.log([...iter]);//[123] - "end value" is ignored
```

Even though it is ignored by the spread operator and for-of loop, javascript iteration interface allow the last IteratorResult to have a value ("end value" in this case). This mean the optional return() method of the interface must return an IteratorResult.

> Question1: Why does return() need to take a value as an argument?

[Es6 spec said](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-54)

> The returned IteratorResult object will typically have a done property whose value is true, and a value property with the value passed as the argument of the return method. However, this requirement is not enforced.